# Bootstrap modal popover hide or close

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem in my modal bootstrap.
I try to create a modal and within the modal create a modal popover.
The result is that is open and not only opens when I click the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-default popover-test" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title" aria-describedby="popover64665">button</a>
    <div class="popover fade right in" role="tooltip" id="popover64665" style="top: 0px; left: 112px; display: block;">
        <div class="arrow" style="top: 50%;"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-title">A Title</h3>
        <div class="popover-content">And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?</div>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

My [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jaztL83/)

Comment: See my answer to [How to open two modal dialogs in Twitter Bootstrap at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23304884/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

1) U need include **jQuery.js** and **bootstrap.js** + **bootstrap.css**

2) It gonna doesnt work without **JS**, so u need set up for example **script.js**

3) set it up in **HTML** `<script src="script.js"></script>`

4) In `script.js` type :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus();
});
```

**Hope it helps...** [**CODEPEN.io**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/objxKg)